# How do I pass JQuery values to next PHP page?

Tags: php, jquery, variables

Background info: I am using Spectrum.js http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/ for a color picker. To utilize this within a form it is set as input type text. This is used in the form to pass the color to a php parser that then passes the value to be combined with a .pov povray file that is then rendered on a unix box.

I am trying to pass the value from this color picker to the next php page. I've spent hours trying to find a solution and came up with nothing.

The weird thing is I am 'alerting' the values out to my tester_done.php page and I can see the correct values in the alert. This works when I have the button just function as a button. When I change the button type to submit though it no longer works. I want to see the values of the color picker when I click submit. Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm pulling my hair out! I just want the values from tester.php to post to tester_done.php and I have no idea why it's not working when I have it alert I get the right values, but when I try to change the button to submit so that values post all I get is rgb<0,0,0>.

Code for tester.php:

```
    <form action="tester_done.php" method="post">
<input type='text' class = "basic" name ="field1" id = "field1"/>
<input type='text' class = "basic2" name ="field2" id = "field2"/>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="send">
</form>

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(".basic").spectrum({
    preferredFormat: "rgb",
    color: "#ffcccc"
}); 



$(".basic2").spectrum({
    preferredFormat: "rgb",
    color: "#ff0"
}); 

jQuery(function(){
    var field1 = $('#field1');
    var field2 = $('#field2');
    $('#send').click(function(){

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "tester_done.php",
            data: {field1value: field1.val(), field2value: field2.val()},
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Code for tester_done.php:

```
 <?php
$base_value=255;
$characters = array("(", "r", "g", "b", ")");

$field1value = isset($_POST['field1value'])? $_POST['field1value'] : ''; 
$nfield1value = str_replace($characters, "", $field1value);
$nsfield1value = $nfield1value;
$nsf1arr = array_map("intval", explode(", ", $nsfield1value));
$c_body_r = $nsf1arr[0] / $base_value; 
$c_body_r_round = round ($c_body_r, 6);
$c_body_g = $nsf1arr[1] / $base_value; 
$c_body_g_round = round ($c_body_g, 6);
$c_body_b = $nsf1arr[2] / $base_value; 
$c_body_b_round = round ($c_body_b, 6);
$c_body = "rgb<".$c_body_r_round.", ".$c_body_g_round.", ".$c_body_b_round.">";
echo $c_body;

$field2value = isset($_POST['field2value'])? $_POST['field2value'] : ''; 
$nfield2value = str_replace($characters, "", $field2value);
$nsfield2value = $nfield2value;
$nsf2arr = array_map("intval", explode(", ", $nsfield2value));
$c_top_r = $nsf2arr[0] / $base_value; 
$c_top_r_round = round ($c_top_r, 6);
$c_top_g = $nsf2arr[1] / $base_value; 
$c_top_g_round = round ($c_top_g, 6);
$c_top_b = $nsf2arr[2] / $base_value; 
$c_top_b_round = round ($c_top_b, 6);
$c_top = "rgb<".$c_top_r_round.", ".$c_top_g_round.", ".$c_top_b_round.">";
echo $c_top;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need JQuery! "< form action="tester_done.php" method="post">" Takes care of posting the data contained within the **input** tags of the *form*.

But, incase you want an ajax response, i will suggest getting rid of the ***action*** attribute, and using ***.serializeArray()*** in the data field of your $.ajax call to pass the data in the *form* as url parameters.

**Possible Usage:** Given that form id="NewForm", $.ajax({type: "POST",
            url: "tester_done.php",
            ***data: $('#NewForm').serializeArray()***,dataType: 'html',success: function(data){alert(data);}});

***NOTE:*** The name of the parameters passed is the same as that of the input tags in your html form, i.e for field1 input, $_POST['field1'] in tester_done.php, when using this method.

Comment: Oh my goodness... thank you. I completely over complicated it. The jquery wasn't necessary I just thought that's what I had to use since the color picker was JQuery. Now I'm just posting like any other form using the input tags. I didn't realize it because I was using field1value in my php and not field1. THANK YOU.

Comment: @Dominick: Glad to help, vote it up, so that other people can use this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `submit` as well:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "tester_done.php",
        data: {field1value: field1.val(), field2value: field2.val()},
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

You can also make the button a simple button (not submit) as before, then submit the form with JavaScript:

```
$('#send').click(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "tester_done.php",
        data: {field1value: field1.val(), field2value: field2.val()},
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    $('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: This would make the most sense to me and I tried that. I am still getting an output of rgb<0,0,0> when it posts to the next page instead of the actual rgb values that I get in the alert.

Comment: thanks for your help, but that still doesn't work. I tried that on a separate page (this tester page eventually gets combined with a form that gets submitted) to see if that would be a workaround and that didn't work either. I'm not sure when the alert works, but when I go to post the values to the PHP page they aren't getting passed. I just keep getting rgb<0,0,0> and that's due to $c_body = "rgb<".$c_body_r_round.", ".$c_body_g_round.", ".$c_body_b_round.">"; so I can only assume the values aren't being received for some reason on tester_done.php.